# Multi select in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, tableview, indexpath

I am not sure what is wrong with the code below. All I'm doing is getting all the rows in the table and marking them as selected, and if they're already selected, I'm deselecting them. Whenever I try this, some of the row index paths are incorrect. There are always a few index paths that are missed every time. What am I doing wrong?

```
let visibleRows = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows

for row in visibleRows! {
    if(self.sections[row.section].files[row.row].type != "cloud"){
        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(row)
        cell?.setSelected(action, animated: true)
        tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(row, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top)
        if(action  == true){
            cell?.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        } else {
            cell?.accessoryType = .None
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("disableOptions", object: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you sure your getting all rows ? Your code is written for VisibleRows.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps

1. Create and initialise a `MutableArray`, probably in the `viewDidLoad`.
2. Add the `indexPath` of a selected `cell`. Do this in the `delegate` method for `cell` selection, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method
3. Check for the `indexPath` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in array. If the `indexPath` exists then handle as the selected `cell`, otherwise as not selected `cell`.
4. Remove the `indexPath` from array if required in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: An `NSMutableIndexSet` is better than an array

Comment: Thanks Paulw11, I just provide the steps to implement, no matter what is the collection object :)

Comment: I am sorry, the issue was not with selecting all, but however I do understand that your way works, perfectly, thank you for your response, I asked another question which describes the exact scenario can you take a look at it,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255463/multi-select-is-not-working-properly-in-ios